# angularjs: how to have scrollbar in select dropdown

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a long list of items in `fileNameLists` and I only want have a scroll-able drop down in select option. ( display around 5 items max and can scroll if it has more).

My code:

```
<select name="fileNameSelected"
                    class="form-control"
                    title="Select File Name"
                    ng-model="fileName"
                    ng-change=""
                    selectpicker=""
                    ng-options="item as item for item in fileNameLists ">
            </select>
```

I tried to add `style="max-height: 30px; overflow-y: scroll;"` in select part but it does not work.

Any idea?

Thanks!

Comment: Try to add size="5" to the select tag

Comment: I did but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add another class to your select

```
<select name="fileNameSelected"
                class="form-control select"
                title="Select File Name"
                ng-model="fileName"
                ng-change=""
                selectpicker=""
                ng-options="item as item for item in fileNameLists ">
</select>
```

and then in css

```
.select{
   height:100px;
   overflow:scroll;
}
```

Will do.

Comment: I would say add some more description which will help to understand your code

Comment: Hi, then I have to added it in CSS? can I do <select name="fileNameSelected" style=" height:100px; overflow:scroll;" .../> in HTML?

Comment: You can Add it either to css or directly to your element as you mentioned in your comment.

Comment: @AniruddhaDas Fixed it as suggested.

Comment: Actually it will help all seeking this answer.  :)